# Common Files across subdomains

Tags: javascript, php, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm currently working across 3 different subdomains and was wondering if there was a way to share files/folders across all of them in one place as they have different roots. That way I can modify a single file without having to duplicate any code across domains.

Is this possible or is this bad practice? are there security concerns?

I'm currently using PHP & JavaScript. If there any better languages/frameworks for this type of structure please let me know.

I've looked at git sub modules but was wondering if there was an easier way that won't make deployment harder. I also considered a sub-directories structure however I don't want to reduce security of the system as I want users within their specific domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think git will be the easiest way if you can use webhook method it will push the changes automatically for all of them, and it's secure too.